# Ubuntu 12.04 as Xen Dom0 with GUI

Tags: gui, xen

i will create a homeserver with Xen who has a graphical user interface (for watching tv, browse the internet etc).
The problem is, if i install xen after my Ubuntu Desktop install, my (dom0) Ubuntu starts only in console mode. Is there a way to combine Xen and Ubuntu with GUI as dom0?

Greets

Answer (score 2):

Are you using a Nvidia graphics card? If yes, did you install the proprietary drivers on your Ubuntu desktop?

To my knowledge, the proprietary Nvidia driver doesn't play well with Xen. If you indeed run your Ubuntu dom0 with an Nvidia card, I suggest you try the following:

1. Boot into your (non-Xen) Ubuntu desktop.
2. Remove the proprietary Nvidia driver and install the open-source Nouveau driver (if you previously blacklisted the Nouveau driver, remove the blacklist entry).
3. Logout/login to see that the Nouveau driver works.
4. Reboot into Xen - you should now have your Ubuntu desktop.

Comment: Hi Powerhouse, thanks for the Answer, i´m using a ATI Graphics card...

Comment: @Michael This answer boils down to "proprietary" kernel modules in general which applies to `fglrx` closed source drivers for AMD cards too (if you have them installed). The Xen kernel is heavily patched and different from regular kernels. That's why you have to install a different kernel package! Most proprietary drivers just aren't designed to run properly with a modified kernel. You should be able to run you graphics card in a DomU (guest) with proper hardware capabilities and run your desktop as a virtual machine.

Comment: @Michael If you don't need Xen specifically, please don't try to use it on a desktop PC with GUI. Alternatives like KVM, VirtualBox, etc. are.